# how to find the distance (in km, or meters) between two cities

Tags: php, html

I am developing a php web site. Here I want to calculate the distance between two cities. For example: user enters Bangalore as departure and Delhi as the arrival place. I want to 
find out the distance between Bangalore and Delhi.

Does anyone know how to do this? I have searched a lot; I don't want to enter the co-ordinates.

Comment: Without entering co-ordinates, the best way is to release a crow and see how far it flies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=NEW+YORK+11535&destinations=WASHINGTON+20544&sensor=false
```

refer this
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Comment: Tks. i got the result. But is it possible to dothis using curl? Then How?.   $post_string='xml?origins=Cochin&destinations=Delhi&mode=Driving&language=en&sensor=false'; $path = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/"; //Relative path to the file with $_POST parsing $ch = curl_init($path); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); //Send the data to the file curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); $val = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch); //Close curl session. Is it ?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:Bangalore%20to:Delhi
```

The format of the q parameter should be from:xxx%20to:yyy. Replace xxx and yyy with the start and destination respectively.
This will return total distance in JSON format: "meters":2077664.

Answer (score 2):

You need the coordinates for both cities (from, to). you could get the coordinates on clientside with googlemaps api. here is a tutorial (php) to calculate distances: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Geo-Targetting-With-PHP-And-MySQL.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Maps API, see [this](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/).